# Apache Spark - ERROR RetryingBlockFetcher: Exception while beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I'm running a Spark Job  in a cluster with the following configuration:

```
--master yarn --deploy-mode client
--executor-memory 4g 
--executor-cores 2 
--driver-memory 6g 
--num-executors 12
```

The problem occurs in the job when I am taking a sample of data in the driver. The command that is run is the following:

```
rddTuplesA.sample(false, 0.03, 261).collect().forEach((tuple) ->
                    //build histogram...
            );
```

The `rddTuplesA` object is of `JavaRDD<Tuple3<String, Double, Double>>` type.

The Job throws the following error:

> 22/04/14 23:19:22 ERROR RetryingBlockFetcher: Exception while
> beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks  java.io.IOException: Failed
> to connect to snf-8802/192.168.0.6:35615
> at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:287)
> at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:218)
> at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$2.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:123)
> at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:153)
> at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.start(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:133)
> at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.fetchBlocks(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:143)
> at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:102)
> at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.fetchRemoteManagedBuffer(BlockManager.scala:1061)
> at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.$anonfun$getRemoteBlock$8(BlockManager.scala:1005)
> at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
> at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBlock(BlockManager.scala:1005)
> at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:1143)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3.$anonfun$run$1(TaskResultGetter.scala:88)
> at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1996)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:63)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection
> refused: snf-8802/192.168.0.6:35615 Caused by:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
> at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
> at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714)
> at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
> at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

However, when I get a smaller sample, the job works perfectly e.g.

```
rddTuplesA.sample(false, 0.01, 261).collect().forEach((tuple) ->
                        //build histogram...
                );
```

Is there any config parameter to change so as to make the job run? It seems that the issue is related to the network. Also, if this occurs due to memory issues, wouldn't there be a memory related error on the Driver? Something like:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: I got the same problem. When it running on small driver, it running pretty well, but show this error on large driverset.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the mystery. The problem relates to the cluster network. Specifically, I added on the /etc/hosts file of each machine (node) their local ip mapped with their hostname (as an alias) like:

```
192.168.0.1 snf-1234
192.168.0.2 snf-1235
...
```

It seems that when the sample was large, the driver was trying to establish a connection that could not be achieved due to the missing matching between the ipv4 and the hostnames.